# Why does my program not match the desired if/else statement?

Tags: java

I do not understand why my program matches the wrong if statement, for example when I use 133 as input, the code will execute with `It's a two digit number.` while I expect it to execute with `It's a three digit number.`

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Input Digits: ");
        int id = input.nextInt();

        if(id >10){
           System.out.print("It's a two digit number");
        }
        
        else if(id >100){
           System.out.print("It's a three digit number");
        }
        
        else if(id >1000){
           System.out.print("It's a four digit number");
        }
        
        else if(id >10000){
           System.out.print("It's a five digit number");
        }
        
        else 
           System.out.print("Number  is not between one- and six-digit number");
    
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Input Digits: 133

It's a two digit number.
```

Comment: Is `id` bigger than 10? Yes! That is why you get that answer.

Comment: Because 133 is greater than 10 (`133 > 10`) the first if condition is matched and its block is executed.  I can see two possible solutions broadly specking.

Comment: Do all the comparisons in the opposite order, from largest to smallest

Comment: Use a debugger to see how the code executes. You will then learn it is different from your expectation but works as designed.

Answer (score 1):

It will execute the first if-statement that it matches, in this case: id>10.

Update your code to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Main { 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Input Digits: ");
    int id = input.nextInt();
  
    if(id >=10000 && id <100000){
       System.out.print("It's a five digit number");
    } else if(id >=1000 && id <100000){
       System.out.print("It's a four digit number");
    } else if(id >=100 && id <100000){
       System.out.print("It's a three digit number");
    } else if(id >=10 && id <100000){
       System.out.print("It's a two digit number");
    } else {
       System.out.print("Number  is not between one- and six-digit number");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add ranges in all conditions. A number bigger than 100000 should print the last statement.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I just made sure that his program correctly implements the logic that he wishes it implements. Further refinements can be made by the OP

Comment: Try running your solution with the value suggested by @Amongalen

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.print("Input Digits: ");
int id = input.nextInt();

if(id >= 10 && id < 100){
    System.out.print("It's a two digit number");
}else if(id >= 100  && id < 1000){
    System.out.print("It's a three digit number");
}else if(id >= 1000  && id < 10000){
    System.out.print("It's a four digit number");
}else if(id >= 10000  && id < 100000){
    System.out.print("It's a five digit number");
}else{
    System.out.print("Number  is not between one- and six-digit number");
}
```

Comment: Please provide some extra explanation about what is wrong with OPs code. Zeke is clearly a new programmer and would love to learn to don't repeated the mistake later.

Comment: You have the same error in all your if conditions, can you spot it? :)